# IIS Server - Post method not working for XML files

Tags: xml, iis

I am new to IIS server and trying to implement a requirement where I need to send a POST request to the XML files located on a IIS server. However I keep getting "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed" error.

The GET method to the XML files is working. It is only the POST method that doesn't work.

By looking online I found that I need to look for "Handler-mappings" . So I tried looking "Handler-mappings" for StaticFile (assuming that this is the handler for the XML files). I see that it already has "all verbs" enabled.

Please let me know how to debug further.

Version: IIS Server 7.5 running on Windows Server 2008

[image: Handler mappings]

Comment: The .xml files are actually VXML files used by the IVR. So a POST method is used by the outdialing method to send parameters to the IVR.

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to fix it by making the web.config entry as below.
I also found an alternative solution where renaming .xml as .aspx also worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="XML" path="*.xml" verb="GET,POST" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="File" requireAccess="None" />
        </handlers>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <add fileExtension=".xml" allowed="true" />
                </fileExtensions>
                <verbs>
                    <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
                </verbs>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```